# Share the same database between a Rails web app and a native app

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, rest

I need to create a Rails app which in the future will need to share the same `database` with a native app.

As I am still quite inexperienced I would like to understand which way is the best to have the 2 app share the same `database`, in this case I will use `postgresql`.

I'm thinking of using `postgrest` for it but I'm unsure if there are any better/ faster ways.

Comment: if you are going to deploy it on heroku there's an option to attach db which acts as addon among multiple apps

Answer (score 2):

> which way is the best to have the 2 app share the same database

The best way is to not share database at all. Mobile app does NOT talk to database directly. Instead, it should talk to an api server, which will provide needed data and perform appropriate checks (user credentials, etc.)

The API server may be implemented as part of the same rails app or a separate app.

Comment: Thank you, I expressed myself wrong. I wanted to ask about the API server.

Comment: @albertomontalesi: in this case, there's nothing to ask about. Just have both apps (if they're separate apps) use the same connection info. If your main rails app also serves api requests, then nothing to do here at all.

Comment: Please see my answer too.

Answer (score 0):

Another way might be to expose a read replica for your database to the mobile which can access the data directly through it via the API calls.

Comment: So is it "directly" or "via api calls"? Also, what if the mobile app needs to _write_ data?

Comment: I believe the mobile app needs to read data only.. if it will write also then API is the only solution

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of options, depending on what you are trying to achieve with the web app. You can look into BAAS's such as Firebase or similar products. However, if you are already using rails, you try the new Rails 5 API mode, where all your controllers and models are preformatted to serve JSON making it slightly easier to get your API up and running for your native app.

An API (to clarify your understanding based on your comments), is a layer that will deal with creating, updating, editing, and deleting things in your database. You will have to define it using your own code (or rails generators if your app is very simple). This layer is so you can insert business logic before the database operation is performed based on the request sent from your app.